# Is there a TGV train from Charles de Gaulle Airport direct to Rochefort?

Tags: trains, transportation, cdg

Is there a TGV train direct from Charles de Gaulle Airport to Rochefort, Nouvelle-
Aquitaine? If so, how can I find a timetable for when it leaves?

Answer (score 5):

There is not, there are no TGV trains to Rochefort. And no other services operate directly between Rochefort and Charles de Gaulle. You can see what train services stop at a French railway station on the [SNCF web site.](https://www.ter.sncf.com/nouvelle-aquitaine/depliant/recherche)

If you are looking to make this route with the least changes, there are a few direct trains from Charles de Gaulle to Bordeaux ([schedule times:](https://en.oui.sncf/en/results?clientId=8c5192a2-d7d9-4904-9c6d-678cfeea2c2b&language=en&country=EN#!/?queryId=jlHh5)) and where you can connect to Rochefort ([schedule times:](https://cdn.ter.sncf.com/medias/PDF/nouvelle_aquitaine/AFFICHES%206%20La%20Rochelle-Saintes-Bordeaux-HIVER_01_02_18_tcm78-171983_tcm78-172306.pdf))

Depending on when you wish to travel, a number of strikes are expected until June. If you're planning on traveling before then be sure to check your exact date and double check nearer the time. Here are the [current dates for strikes.](https://faq.trainline.eu/article/674-sncf-french-rail-strikes-2018)